# Lightbox that works with dynamically loaded html

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I'm currently using a read more function on the frontpage of my site to load in larger sections of articles.  It loads from a seperate html file a div with the id mainarticle.  It makes use of the jQuery function .load() but the lightbox within this section does not work.

I know it is something to do with .live() but I am unable to pinpoint the function that I need to change to a live() function.

I'm currently using jQuery lightbox; does anyone know of an existing lightbox that works with loaded in content, or how I can modify one to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What live does, is attach events to elements that exist on page or will appear on page.

You probably have lightbox open bound to some elements click event. change that code from

```
$('element').bind('click', function(event){
  open lightbox here
});
```

to

```
$('element').live('click', function(event){
  open lightbox here
});
```

and you are done.

Comment: I tried this and it has no effect on the loaded content, and stops the plugin working on the single page article.

Comment: It all depends how you use lightbox. And of course, which box you use. Some of those boxes start their script themselves. And that is bad for me (and you probably.). Use those boxes, which you initialize yourself. then you can use them like i showed in my example. For that reason solutions like fancybox (http://fancybox.net/) or simplemodal(http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) have been best for me.